# my PHP MySQL syntax is too long

Tags: php, mysql

Thank you, very nice solution, that was answered my question.
How can I use your solution if my $sql is as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_main, $tbl_country, $tbl_members
WHERE ($tbl_main.country_id = $tbl_country.country_id) AND ($tbl_main.member_id = $theselect) ORDER BY $chosenTable.$orderby LIMIT $startpoint, $limit";
```

i.e. how can I use your solution somewhere in the middle of a code.

Comment: You should really normalize your database instead of having to do this at all. Instead of having one table for each country, you will probably be better off with all countries in one table.

Answer (score 4):

You can conditionally concatenate the extra condition:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_main, $tbl_country, $tbl_members
WHERE ($tbl_main.country_id = $tbl_country.country_id)";

if(isset($theselect)) {
    $sql .= " AND ($tbl_main.member_id = $theselect)"; 
}

$sql .= " ORDER BY $chosenTable.$orderby LIMIT $startpoint, $limit";
```

Comment: Thank you, very nice solution, that was answered my question.
How can I use your solution if my $sql is as follows:

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_main, $tbl_country, $tbl_members
 WHERE ($tbl_main.country_id = $tbl_country.country_id) AND ($tbl_main.member_id = $theselect) ORDER BY $chosenTable.$orderby LIMIT $startpoint, $limit";

i.e. how can I use your solution somewhere in the middle of a code.